# Template 10:Hamburger Basic UI

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, template10

I am developing a UWP app and I would like to make it look like the ms news  app so just like in the news app when I click the Hamburger button it should not shift the title of the page to its right side rather it should do nothing to the title  side.

What I get:

[image: By default]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Also Secondly what should I do so after clicking the hamburger button when the pane is opened and I click on anywhere other than the Panel like on the grid or on PageHeader the Hamburger control  should close automatically just like in the news app.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, more specifically http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done by doing this:

```
  <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu"
                HamburgerBackground="#FFD13438"
                HamburgerForeground="White"
                NavAreaBackground="#FF2B2B2B"
                NavButtonCheckedBackground="#FFD13438"
                SecondarySeparator="White"
                NavButtonForeground="White"
                **VisualStateWideDisplayMode="CompactOverlay"**
                        >
```